# How to disable a table if two values are equal?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I tried to disable a table by using JavaScript if two input values are equal.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function checkEnableTable() {
        var totalacceptedload = document.getElementById('totalacceptedload'),
        var maximumload = document.getElementById('maximumload'),
        tablecoursedistribution = document.getElementById('tablecoursedistribution');
        tablecoursedistribution.disabled = (totalacceptedload.value = maximumload.value);
    }
    window.onload = checkEnableTable;
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

> My Html

```
    <input id="totalacceptedload" class ="alert alert-success" value ="<?php if (!isset($count_course_choice)):?><?php else: echo $count_course_choice['contact_hours'];?><?php endif ?>"/>

<input id="maximumload" class ="alert alert-danger" value ="<?php if (!isset($eee_setting)): ?><?php else:echo $eee_setting['maximum_course_choice'];?><?php endif ?>"/>
<table id="tablecoursedistribution" >

</table>
```

Comment: You should use `totalacceptedload.value === maximumload.value` for boolean comparison.  You are currently using assignment `=`.

Comment: @Kavka I try what you suggested but still not working. are you able to show me another way to this .. pls

Comment: Apparently you cannot disable tables in the sense that you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899453/how-to-disable-and-enable-html-table-using-javascript The `<table>` element does not even have a `disabled` property.  Your code is just adding that property to the object.

Comment: how can i able to hide table if two value is equal instead of disable.

Comment: `tablecoursedistribution.style.visibility = (totalacceptedload.value == maximumload.value) ? "hidden" : "visible"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function checkEnableTable() {
    tablecoursedistribution.style.visibility = (totalacceptedload.value == maximumload.value) ? "hidden" : "visible"
}

var totalacceptedload = document.getElementById('totalacceptedload'),
    maximumload = document.getElementById('maximumload'),
    tablecoursedistribution = document.getElementById('tablecoursedistribution');

window.onload = checkEnableTable;
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/y9Xk7/).

I made it so that if you enter two equal values in the box, then click the button, the table is hidden, otherwise it is shown.

HTH

Comment: Is it possible to hide table without click on button?. by window.onload

Comment: Yeah, sure. My example above will do that. The button thing was just to give you the chance to play around with it.

Comment: but window.onload is not working ! but thing working well. i don't know why?

Comment: Without seeing  the rest of your code, it is difficult to say.

Comment: Thank you So much Jack Zelig, Problem is solved, may i get your email address?

Comment: You can contact me via the contact form on my website. Check my user profile for the address.

Answer (score 1):

this statement first check both values if equal then assign true to tablecoursedistribution.disabled otherwise false to tablecoursedistribution.disabled

```
tablecoursedistribution.disabled = (totalacceptedload.value == maximumload.value) ? "true" : "false" ;
```

Comment: its not working is it possible to disable a table by javascript ?

Comment: why not you remove or hide the table if values are equal

Comment: Its a great idea as i newbie would help me to implement this hide process fully. please.